# NetworkX shortest_path with Qgis shape

Tags: python, networkx, qgis

I use pyqgis and i need to know the distance between one point from a shape, and all points from another shape. But i need to calculate the path on a third shape. I try:

```
nx.shortest_path_length(G,source = imb, target = pmz)
```

but i have a error :

> The node < qgis._core.QgsFeature objet at 0x000009DAB7378> is not in the graph

I think my points need to be in the graph but i didn't know how to do that and how to get them when they are in cause i need to do iteration.

Have you any idea how I can do this?
Tank you

EDIT :

I have shape imb ( list of bulding ) 
shape pmz (one point)
and shape route ( roads )

i defined like that :

```
imb = self.dlg.coucheimb.itemData(self.dlg.coucheimb.currentIndex())
route = self.dlg.route.itemData(self.dlg.route.currentIndex())
pmz = self.dlg.pmz.itemData(self.dlg.pmz.currentIndex())
```

i create a graph with my shape road :

```
path = route.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
            index = path.find("|layerid")
            path = path[:index].replace("\\","/")
            path = path.encode('latin-1')


            H = nx.read_shp(path)
            G = nx.Graph(H)
```

Then i try to use shortest_paht_length :

```
 for i in imb:
                short = nx.shortest_path_length(G,source = i, target = pmz)
                print short
```

But i have error

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: ok, i edited the question

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyqgis.  So to help, I'll need something that is really complete - if I copy and paste this into python I need to get the error you get.  With this code, there's things that need to be imported, and some data that's needed to create the networks.  It needs to be "complete".

Comment: Something that will help is to do the commands `G.has_node(i)` and `G.has_node(pmz)`.  It looks like one of these nodes isn't in `G`.  So ultimately the question that needs to be answered is where do you think that node is being added to `G`, and why isn't it?

Comment: It's my problem, i know i never added my points to G but i didn't know how to add them and iterate on them in my loop. Cause G have already node from my shape route. Tank you for your help